# css label on focus not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to reduce the size of the label on focus fro the text to be entered. Bring it back to the same size if no text entered or on click somewhere else. Below is the code snippet I am trying.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
div:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  tansition: ease;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
label {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0">
  <label>Three-colored border!</label>
</div>
```

Can this be achieved only in CSS or do i need to include any javascript or angular js?

Comment: `if no text entered or on click somewhere else` - when no text is entered where? Is there some input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you intend to accept text using this div but to achieve the reduction of label font size, you can add `div:focus label { font-size: 14px; }` to your css and it'll reduce on focus.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
div:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  transition: ease;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
div:focus label {
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: font 1s ease
}
label {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: font 1s ease
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0">
  <label>Three-colored border!</label>
</div>
```

Update: font reduction now goes in transition with the div

Answer (score 0):

Css is for styling the elements only. The problem is detecting if input is empty. You cannot analyze the element with css. For that You need JS. `var size = $("input").text().length;` 
And in html put **onfocusout** function to check the size. `<label onfocusout="fn()">Three-colored border!</label>`
When putting it together

```
function fn() {
    var size = $("label").text().length;
    if (size>0) {
        $("div").addClass("goodClass");
    } else {
        $("div").addClass("badClass");
    }
}
```

And of course, those style included in classes.